# ERROR running force:source:delete - The delete operation failed in the org. Review the error messages below

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am trying to delete an `Aura Component` by right clicking on the file contents and selecting:

> SFDX: Delete This from Project and Org

But it's not working...

I get this message in the output panel:

> Starting SFDX: Delete from Project and Org
>
> sfdx force:source:delete --sourcepath c:\path\file.cmp --noprompt
>
> ERROR:  The delete operation failed in the org. Review the error messages below, delete any files locally if needed, and re-run the command if applicable.
>
> ERROR running force:source:delete:  The delete operation failed in the org. Review the error messages below, delete any files locally if needed, and
>   re-run the command if applicable.
>
> sfdx force:source:delete --sourcepath c:\path\file.cmp --noprompt ended with exit code 1

But there is no `error message below` to review.

The file is not referenced in any other files. 
All other related `aura` files have been deleted, there is only the `.cmp` and `.cmp-meta.xml`

Why won't it delete?

Comment: Have you tried manually issuing the command like below  sfdx force:source:delete --sourcepath c:\path\file.cmp --noprompt --loglevel=ERROR --json to see if you receive anything . Also have you looked into your orgs deployment status to see if there are any failures

Comment: is the component added to any other components or lightning page layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI sometime can be buggy to show the errors . I had issues last week and got resolved when i updated the CLI using `sfdx update`

The salesforce deployment status would give much better error . Go to Deploy > Deployment Status in your org when you execute command to see if there are any failures during that .

Also it could be way the vscode extension is issuing the command it might not revealing much error

Manually in your terminal run below

```
sfdx force:source:delete --sourcepath c:\path\file.cmp --noprompt --loglevel=ERROR --json
```

Comment: Running the command as suggested revealed that the file was locked. I restarted VS Code and ran the command again from the terminal and it worked.